# Writing a Large File C# with System.IO

Tags: c#, .net

I am implementing the following code to write a large file from disk over http in a generic handler. My download speeds start really quick but slow down as the download progresses. I tried increasing the size of the buffer to 100k but same results. Anyone have any ideas, perhaps I need to look at something unmanaged?

Thanks!

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/812406

Comment: I see no code, did you forget to add it?

Comment: Have you looked at the server config that you are uploading to?  Often an http upload will be configured with a max file size it will accept in order to prevent attacks.

Comment: The code is in the url below. I haven't looked at the server config. Where would I look at that? Would it be an IIS Setting? Thanks!